# Python, With ... as ... AST/Symbol access

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.6

> Disclaimer: Sensible semantics do dictate that the LHS of as behaving differently depending on the RHS lexeme is ludicrous. But I am curious nontheless.

Hi guys,

Simple question, but one that somone may be able to answer better than my hack. I'm currently messing with metaclasses etc and working out a comfortable syntax for some things.

Given the Python `with ... as ...:` statement, can I access in the context manager what name(s) are given on the right of `as`:

```
with foo('fido') as Dog:
    ...
```

Can `foo.__enter__()` find out the lexeme where `Dog` is?

Super bonus credit: Keep it implementation agnostic, supporting Python 3.x too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just like (say) in `Dog = foo('fido')` there is no "serious" way in which `foo` can know its result is about to be bound to name `Dog` in the caller.  (By "serious" I'm excluding rummaging in the stack to find out the calling bytecode and disassembling it, &c -- basically the stuff that you know you'd never do if you knew your code was going to be maintained by a well-muscled maintainer who knows where you live;-).

Comment: +1 True. Thanks for your reply. I know that sensible code should not take into account the lexeme also ;)